# What am I doing wrong?

Tags: help

OK So I put my "Tor" onto my Flash Drive instead of my hard drive... Is that OK to run it from there? (I figured, it's just on "F" instead of "C")

*problem*

I type into the text box (*on the Tor Browser with the green onion logo on it*)... - "Adobe Photoshop CC X6 2014" and then a couple of pages of links pops up, (Just like as if I'm using Google as usual) ...

So... I click on one, and instead of taking to the download for Photoshop, it takes me to a download for "ilivid" download manager. Why? Do I NEED to have "ilivid" to download the new Photoshop?

I keep my "private Firewall 7.0" on while using Tor, is that OK? or could that be causing my problem with my links being hijacked?

I must say that I'm totally new to "Tor" I never heard of it before tonight. I used to always use Warez websites, and chatrooms, like www.needfullthingz.com but I'd really like to become an integral part of this. I don't understand the lingo yet either.

Should I be giving/using my regular old e-mail address that I've had for years with Gmail or optimum.net? or do I need to make and/or open up a another/newer one somewhere?